# Delete individual emails in a thread

Tags: pantheon-mail

I am struggling to find an option to delete individual emails in a conversation. The delete function purges the whole conversation but I would like to delete just one email in a 10-email conversation. Any secret keyboard shortcut or something?

Answer (score 2):

**Nope**, there is no built-in way to do this. I've requested it as a feature [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-mail/+bug/1629743), where I suggest you subscribe as well, in case devs want feedback. If you'd like to request the feature more prominently, try [creating a developer bounty](https://www.bountysource.com/teams/elementary/bounties).